# C# program freezes for a minute when running a bunch of RegExes

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I have a program that runs a large number of regular expressions (10+) on a fairly long set of texts (5-15 texts about 1000 words each)

Every time that is done I feel like I forgot a Thread.Sleep(5000) in there somewhere. Are regular expressions really processor-heavy or something? It'd seem like a computer should crank through a task like that in a millisecond.

Should I try and group all the regular expressions into ONE monster expression? Would that help?

Thanks

EDIT: Here's a regex that runs right now:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"((.*(\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*).*)|(.*(keyword1)).*|.*(keyword2).*|.*(keyword3).*|.*(keyword4).*|.*(keyword5).*|.*(keyword6).*|.*(keyword7).*|.*(keyword8).*|.*(count:\n[0-9]|count:\n\n[0-9]|Count:\n[0-9]|Count:\n\n[0-9]|Count:\n).*|.*(keyword10).*|.*(summary: \n|Summary:\n).*|.*(count:).*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Regex regex = new Regex(@".*(\.com|\.biz|\.net|\.org|\.co\.uk|\.bz|\.info|\.us|\.cm|(<a href=)).*", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It's pretty huge, no doubt about it. The idea is if it gets to any of the keywords or the link it will just take out the whole paragraph surrounding it.

Comment: You should probably run those RegExes on a background thread if it is freezing the gui.

Comment: Regular expressions can be expensive. Their syntax can give the illusion that they're working magic, but under the hood they're not always efficient. If possible, you should `Compile` the regex to increase performance.

Comment: You can try to parallelize your code using `Parallel.For`, `Parallel.ForEach`, `Parallel.Invoke` (under `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace)

Comment: So ... where are the regular expressions? Which ones are slow on which word sets? (5, 10, 15 and 1000 are small numbers). Profiling shows what? (10 * 15 is a relatively small number of runs.)

Comment: Show us your regular expressions and the code. There's no way we can answer your question without seeing them. Running 10 regular expressions 15 times each should be very quick. But if your expressions are poorly constructed then it could take a very, very long time.

Comment: I added the snippets, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexes don't kill CPU's, regex authors do.  ;)

But seriously, if regexes always ran as slowly as you describe, nobody would be using them.  Before you start loading up silver bullets like the `Compiled` option, you should go back to your regex and see if it can be improved.

And it can.  Each keyword is in its own branch/alternative, and each branch starts with `.*`, so the first thing each branch does is consume the remainder of the current paragraph (i.e., everything up to the next newline).  Then it starts backtracking as it tries to match the keyword.  If it gets back to the position it started from, the next branch takes over and does the same thing.

When all branches have reported failure, the regex engine bumps ahead one position and goes through all the branches again.  That's over a dozen branches, times the number of characters in the paragraph, times the number of paragraphs... I think you get the point.  Compare that to this regex:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^.*?(\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*|keyword1|keyword2|keyword3|keyword4|keyword5|keyword6|keyword7|keyword8|count:(\n\n?[0-9]?)?|keyword10|summary: \n).*$", 
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

There are three major changes:

- I factored out the leading and trailing `.*`
- I changed the leading one to `.*?`, making it non-greedy
- I added start-of-line and end-of-line anchors (`^` and `$` in `Multiline` mode)

Now it only makes one match attempt per paragraph (pass or fail), and it practically never backtracks.  I could probably make it even more efficient if I knew more about your data.  For example, if every keyword/token/whatever starts with a letter, a word boundary would have an appreciable effect (e.g. `^.*?\b(\w+...`).

The `ExplicitCapture` option makes all the "bare" groups (`(...)`) act like non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`), reducing the overhead a little more without adding clutter to the regex.  If you want to capture the token, just change that first group to a named group (e.g.`(?<token>\w+...`).

Comment: Thanks for enlightening the newb :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you may try Compiled option [RegexOptions.Compiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)

Here is good article about regex performance: [regex-performance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-performance)

Second one: regex performance depended on pattern:
Some pattern are much quicker than others. You have to cpecify pattern as strict as possible.

And the third one.
I had some troubles with regex perfomance. And in that case I used string.contains method.
For example:

```
bool IsSomethingValid(stging source, string shouldContain, string pattern)
{
    bool res = source.Contains(shouldContain);
    if (res)
    {
         var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
         res = regex.IsMatch(source);
    }
    return res;
}
```

If you gave us an examples of your script we may try to improve them.

Answer (score 1):

Never assume anything about what and for which reason your application is slow. Instead, always *measure* it.

Use a decent performance profiler (like e.g. [Red Gate's ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) - they offer a free 14 days trial version) and actually see the performance bottlenecks.

My own experience is that I always was wrong on what was the real cause for a bad performance. With the help of profiling, I could find the slow code segments and adjust them to increase performance.

If the profiler confirms your assumption regarding the Regular Expressions, you then could try to optimize them (by modifying or pre-compiling them).

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern doesn't deal with case...don't have the ignore case option. See

[Want faster regular expressions? Maybe you should think about that IgnoreCase option...](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/03/20/93379.aspx)

Otherwise as mentioned but put in here:

1. Put all operations on seperate background threads. Don't hold up a gui.
2. Examine each pattern. To many usages of * (zero to many) if swapped out to a + (one to many) can give the regex engine an real big hint and not require as much *fruitless* backtracking. See ([Backtracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4.aspx))
3. Compiling a pattern can take time, use Compile option to avoid it being parsed again...but if one uses the static methods to call the regex parser, the pattern is cached automatically.
4. See [Regex hangs with my expression [David Gutierrez]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/02/10/370690.aspx) for some other goodies.